# How to compile a js file as library using webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-loader

Hi how do I compile a single js class file as library using webpack to generate an output that can be included in script tag

`<script src='demo/demo.js'></script>`

and also an output that can be import

`import demo from 'demo'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `demo` library in different environments such as AMD, CommonJS, Nodejs. You need to use `output.library` option with its type set to `'umd'`.

Besides, we need to set [output.globalObject](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject) to  option to `'this'`

> When targeting a library, especially the libraryTarget is 'umd', this option indicates what global object will be used to mount the library. To make UMD build available on both browsers and Node.js, set output.globalObject option to 'this'.

An example:

`demo/src/demo.js`:

```js
export class Demo {
  sayHello() {
    console.log("hello!");
  }
}
```

`demo/webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/demo.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "lib"),
    filename: "demo.js",
    library: {
      name: "demo",
      type: "umd",
    },
    globalObject: "this",
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`demo/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "lib/demo.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

---

Consumer side

Use the `demo` library in the browser by `script` tag:

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src='./demo/lib/demo.js'></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = () => {
      const { Demo } = window.demo;
      const demo = new Demo()
      demo.sayHello();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Use the `demo` in `index.js` file by ES6 `import` syntax.

`index.js`:

```js
import { Demo } from "./demo/lib/demo";

const d = new Demo();
d.sayHello();
```

Consumer side `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    filename: "index-bundled.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

After generating the `index-bundled.js` file, run `node index-bundled.js`. Output:

```
⚡  node index-bundled.js 
hello!
```